# Find the energy stored in the capacitor

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework

For the circuit shown in the figure. Assume that the swich is closed at t = 0

Find the final energy stored in the capacitor?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because homework questions without an attempt at a solution will be closed. You call yourself "electron" so this should be easy for you.

Comment: @Andyaka as an electron i closed it and at same time i didnt ...

Comment: Yes I follow your humour. Some maybe won't

Comment: to add to what @Wheatley answered, apply source transformation on the current source and 10 ohm resistor and you will have one less loop in the circuit.

Comment: "Superposition" will make this easy to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The energy stored in a capacitor is equal to 1/2 * C * V²

Find the steady state voltage (clue: at the steady state, the capacitor acts as an open circuit), and then compute the stored energy using the formula above.